My React Native app doesn't shown on my phsical android device
I started to learn some react native to build android app 2 days ago, and everything worked well until yesterday night, I had the close VSCode and then i wanted to make some change on my app UI, when i type  npx expo start, my expo go app showed that default screen. That one
I searched web for possible solutions but i couldn't find something but Expo Go Docs I did all the updates and fix in there but it didnt worked
App Info's for my Expo Go in my Physical Android Device:
Client Version: 2.31.2
Supported SDK's: SDK 51
Version Info's for my Expo and some other stuff in my PC:
When i type [npx react-native upgrade]: You are on the most recent stable release of React Native: 0.74.3
This is all i can provide for now, if you need any information to help, i will do my best.
Thanks in advance.

I think my app crashes after installing libraries. I created new project and installed some libraries for components, after receiving some error messages I decided to remove the library that I installed. Then I get that screen again.

Try yarn start --reset-cache . Have you tried it with expo online? All else fails, delete all node_modules and either try yarn or npm install again although I dont think thats the issue, show some code please
